# Link between zoho crm and Moodle

Tags: crm, moodle, zoho

I want to know if i take a website to lead form from zoho crm and integrate it into my moodle website and someone registers to my site with that form. Can the information be sent to both my moodle database and my zoho crm account. If so can someone explain to me how to do it.. Please please please

Answer (score 0):

This can definitely be done.  The Zoho API for these things is fairly robust.  Try oDesk or Guru.com and search for zoho developers.  Just clearly define what you are looking for and then throw it out there for some bids.  It should not be expensive.  This is an example query:
[Zoho talent at Guru](http://www.guru.com/find-freelancers/Zoho-Experts-Developers/0ZJ-FG4CC9?gclid=CK-ZhYXD8agCFcTt7QodxwKq_w)